# service class should implement on feature module or separately

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm having a component (UserInformation), which is inside the shared folder, is uses different modules. Component HTML file contains 2 anchor tags with click event.
eg -

```
 <a (click)="userClicked($event)"> {{userInfo.FullName}} </a>
```

UserInformation component uses by other feature modules as well. 
For example, Feature module 1 and feature module 2 uses the UserInformation.

my problem is where can i park the service class for implementation of click event, click event behave differently according to modules.

Is the service class should inside feature module? if then, how can i implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an interface that your components have to implement.

```
export interface IUserInformation {
  userClicked(event: any);
  userInfo: {
    FullName: string;
  }
}
```

Now all your components using this shared component must implement this class :

```
export class FirstComponent implements IUserInformation {
  ...
}
```

If your component doesn't declare `userClicked` and `userInfo`, your linter will throw an error.

Comment: Looks like this is exactly what I'm looking for, let me integrate with this my code.